# GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling is not working

Tags: github, jenkins

I tried to setup a Github trigger for my repository. Ideal behavior is when there is a pull request, Jenkins will run tests before it merges to master. I added Jenkins hook url with format *http://ABC:8080/job/git_test/*. But it seems when I submit a pull request, nothing happened.

Git plugin version 3.1.0

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

You can make of use of the URL like below:

http://ABC:8080/github-webhook/

which would be your jenkins url.